# Mysql GROUP_CONCAT multiplies based on count

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

I'm trying to make a mysql query that GROUP_CONCAT's all strings from the table 'shop_previews'.
When running the following query however, it repeats it based on the amount of "timesBought".

```
select 
    `shop_items`.*, 
     group_concat(shop_previews.image) as images, 
     count(`shop_histories`.`shopId`) as `timesBought` 
from `shop_items`
left join `shop_previews` on `shop_previews`.`shopId` = `shop_items`.`id`
left join `shop_histories` on `shop_items`.`id` = `shop_histories`.`shopId`
group by `shop_items`.`id` 
order by `timesBought` desc
```

So if timesBought equals to two, and there was only one result from shop_previews.image, it would concat that one entry with itself, resulting in something like

```
https://example.com/example.png,https://example.com/example.png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` supports `DISTINCT`:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT shop_previews.image) as images
```